# Managing version files of Core data model

Tags: ios5, core-data

During development process we keep on changing core data model file.Supposing we have many model files each built on previous version.  Then At the time of submitting the app to appstore can I delete all the versions except the latest one and the one on which it is based.

Basically how to manage all version files??

Comment: What version control system are you using for the rest of the code?  I recommend git but any modern DVCS should work for this task.

Comment: No..I mean t core data model file.Whenever I have to do changes in core data model file , I make a new version and light weight migration.But there will be many such files in development cycle so how to deal with that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During pre-1.0 development it's much more typical to not bother with model versioning. Edit the model as needed, don't create new versions, and delete your existing data whenever it doesn't match the new model version. This would be a bad idea *after* release, but while in development it's usually fine.

If you do need to maintain different versions during development for some reason, there are really no special steps to take to get rid of the old ones. Make sure that the latest model version is the current version (which will almost certainly be true anyway) and then delete the old model files. Voila, you're done. You don't need the old model files unless people will be using the app who already have data that uses those models, and when you first release the app, that will not be the case.

Comment: By "delete the old model files", do you mean delete them in the finder?

Comment: I mean delete them from the Xcode project. When you do that, Xcode will offer to move them to the trash, which you probably want to do in this situation.